# How can I learn Sunday's string searching algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, strings

How does Sunday's string searching algorithm work?

I am highly unskilled in processing mathematical lingo, so I would appreciate a use case/example.

A link would be ok. I tried searching the first 6 pages for terms "sunday's algorithm", "sunday's string search", "sunday algorithm example" but all I ever found were comparisons to other algorithms, or horrible, incomprehensible google translates to English.

Comment: From what I can tell, Sunday's algorithm is essentially an improved Boyer-Moore. So isn't it natural that it would be described in comparison to that algorithm? It seems that the best way to learn Sunday's algorithm is to learn Boyer-Moore first. That's a very well-known algorithm that's described in many textbooks and websites.

Comment: Can you give *any* reference that would help us know which algorithm you mean?

Comment: @Raphael There's this [page by H.W. Lang](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/sundayen.htm) which gives pseudocode and cites Sunday's original paper (D.M. Sunday, *A Very Fast Substring Search Algorithm*. *Comm. ACM*, 33(8):132-142,1990).

Comment: Thanks, @DavidRicherby! NukeTheMoon, you need to include this (or another reference) in your question and explain what in this exposition you do not understand.